# Is it possible to set retries (maxAttempts) number for specific task in queue?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I know how to set retries (maxAttempts) for a queue.

```
gcloud tasks queues update test-queue --max-attempts=5
```

But is there any way to setup retries number for specific task in that queue ?

I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55577504/how-to-override-the-retry-configuration-for-google-cloud-tasks-node-js-client),  but it looks like those options setup for some RPC related stuff.

``

Answer (score 0):

At this time, you are unable to set retries by task, only by queue.